# Scala: how do I access a Class[?0] type?

Tags: scala, types

As Daniel suggests, I omitted a lot of information, so here's what I'm trying to do:

I just have a POJO like class

```
class MyDataObj(val a:String, val b:Boolean)
```

and I want to transform an instance of it in a SQL insert statement. I was suggested to use this snippet:

```
val o = new MyDataObj("word", false)
val attributes = o.getClass.getDeclaredMethods.filter { _.getReturnType != Void.TYPE
}.map {
method => (method.getName, method.getReturnType, method.invoke(o))
}
```

that returns a Array like this:

```
Array[(String, Class[?0], Object) forSome { type ?0 }] = Array((a,class java.lang.String,word))
```

I cannot figure out how to access to the type between the brackets of Class in order to evaluate how to build my SQL statement: in case of Class[String] I need to enclose the third element of the tuple in quotes, in case of Class[int] or Class[boolean] I just need to return the value as String with no enclosure.

Hope it is enough clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are barking at the wrong tree. :)

The method return type is `Class[_]` -- a `Class` whose type parameter may be anything, but you do not need to know the type parameter: the class is what you want! You can just get its string representation, for example:

```
scala> attributes(0)._2.toString
res3: String = boolean

scala> attributes(1)._2.toString
res4: String = class java.lang.String
```

Or you can get the canonical name:

```
scala> attributes(0)._2.getCanonicalName
res7: String = boolean

scala> attributes(1)._2.getCanonicalName
res8: String = java.lang.String
```

Comment: I just re-entered my question with more details. Take a look please.

Comment: Thanks, getCanonicalName is what I was looking for. Now that you made me get what a Type is I realize the solution was really straightforward... I wonder how long will it take to me to get a clear understanding of Scala (it's just three weeks so far) and considering I have no Java backgrounds I suppose it will take long.

Comment: @Max Off topic, but [Coursera's functional programming in scala](https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun) is just starting in little over two weeks. I highly recommend it: it's free, and it won't too much of your time.

Comment: Very insightful answer.